# LPTHW Ex 16, imy ssues with my own script

Tags: python-2.7

I successfully completed ex16 in LPTHW and now I'm trying to replicate it in my own script to better understand the lesson. I typed the following but the shell returns with:

File "bruce.py", line 23, in 
  scribble.truncate()
I0Error: File not open for writing

My script is as follows:

```
 from sys import argv
 script, file_name=argv
 scribble=open(file_name)

  print "Master Bruce, here is your file: %s" % file_name

  print scribble.read()

 print """

 Master Bruce, to change the contents of the file 
 simply press ENTER and type three lines:

 """

  line1=raw_input("line 1:")
  line2=raw_input("line 2:")
  line3=raw_input("line 3:")

  print "Just a few seconds Master Bruce..."

  scribble.truncate()

  scribble.write(line1,line2,line3)

  scribble.close
```

My understanding is that the file was opened in line 5 already. I also tried scibble.open() on line 22 but that didnt work either. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please use the "code" "{}" formatting for the code, remove the newlines unless they are part of the code - some peoble copy the code and run it and then extra linenumbers are a source of more work...just trying to help you getting a higher probability of getting a reasonable answer, please edit your question.

Comment: I just removed the number on the left column and used the brackets as instructed. Is this better?

Comment: I meant the brackets from the menu to indicate that it is "code", see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: the file isn't open for **writing**. You opened it in read-only mode.

```
scribble=open(file_name)
```

is equivalent to

```
scribble=open(file_name, "r")
```

You need to open the file in read/write mode. Since you don't want to truncate it at the start and don't want to append to it, use **r+**.

```
scribble=open(file_name, "r+")
```

You should brush up on the documentation for open() [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Incidentally, you should also look into opening files with the **with** keyword [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) for cleaner handling.

```
with open(file_name, "r+") as scribble:
    # do things
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I was able to change it to r+ and for the 'write' portion I used the following:
  
scribble.write("\n%s\n%s\n%s"%(line1,line2,line3))

Answer (score 0):

> The most commonly-used values of *mode* are `'r'` for reading [...]. If *mode* is omitted, it defaults to `'r'`.
>
> [...]
>
> Modes `'r+'`, `'w+'` and `'a+'` open the file for updating (reading and writing); note that `'w+'` truncates the file.

[source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Ahhh, so i just have to add 'r+w' under the defined variable scribble and replace 'print scribble.read()' with just 'print scribble'?